# How to store result of json extractor to csv file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to extract some particular fields from json list response
following snapshot shows the json expression
[image]

Below image is my response:
[image]

How can i store this response i.e., name and id to a csv file. please suggest the best solution.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can go for [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), the relevant code would be something like:

```
1.upto(vars.get('enrolledDevices_matchNr') as int, { idx ->
    def enrolledDevice = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('enrolledDevices_' + idx))
    new File('myfile.csv') << enrolledDevice.name << ',' << enrolledDevice.id << System.getProperty('line.separator')
})
```

More information: [Groovy Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)